# What is the best way to make these function into a class? Or multiple classes?

Tags: function, class

I am looking for any advice on how to turn a function into a class.  I will enter a program below. It is long. I feel i should place the whole thing in for context. I need to rewrite it so that i will use classes in place of the three functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Do not change these function prototypes:
void readBig(int[]);
void printBig(int[]);
void addBig(int[], int[], int[]);

// This constant should be 100 when the program is finished.
const int MAX_DIGITS = 100;


int main()
     {
     // Declare the three numbers, the first, second and the sum:
     int number1[MAX_DIGITS], number2[MAX_DIGITS], sum[MAX_DIGITS];
     bool finished = false;     
     char response;
     while (! finished)
         {
         cout << "Please enter a number up to " << MAX_DIGITS << " digits: ";
         readBig(number1);
         cout << "Please enter a number up to " << MAX_DIGITS << " digits: ";
         readBig(number2);
         addBig(number1, number2, sum);
         printBig(number1);
         cout << "\n+\n";
         printBig(number2);
         cout << "\n=\n";
         printBig(sum);
         cout << "\n";
         cout << "test again?";
         cin>>response;
         cin.ignore(900,'\n');
         finished = toupper(response)!= 'Y';
         }
     return 0;
     }
//ReadBig will read a number as a string,
//It then converts each element of the string to an integer and stores it in an integer array.
//Finally, it reverses the elements of the array so that the ones digit is in element zero,
//the tens digit is in element 1, the hundreds digit is in element 2, etc.

//AddBig adds the corresponding digits of the first two arrays and stores the answer in the third.
//In a second loop, it performs the carry operation.

//PrintBig uses a while loop to skip leading zeros and then uses a for loop to print the number.
//FUNCTIONS GO BELOW


void readBig(int number[MAX_DIGITS])

{
    string read="";
    cin>>read;
    int len,i, save=0;
    len= read.length();

    while(i<MAX_DIGITS){
        number[i]=0;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0;  i <= len-1; i++){
        number[i] = int (read.at(i)-'0');
    }
        for (i=0;i<=len/2-1;i++){
        save=number[i];
        number[i]=number[len-1-i];
        number[len-1-i]=save;

        }
}

void printBig(int number[MAX_DIGITS])
{
        int digit=MAX_DIGITS-1; 
        while(number[digit]==0){
            digit--;
        }
        for (int i=digit; i>=0; i--) 
           {cout<<number[i];
        }
}
void addBig(int number1[MAX_DIGITS], int number2[MAX_DIGITS], int sum[MAX_DIGITS])
{
    // The code below sums the arrays.

    for (int i = MAX_DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sum[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];

        if (sum[i] > 9 && i < MAX_DIGITS - 1)
        { 
            sum[i + 1] += 1;
            sum[i] -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```